# auto refresh in php code not working

Tags: php, refresh

i trying to make auto refresh work in PHP code.

This code is to include a news article with a blog under and also 'ref docs', however when you post a comment, the blog form and postings appear twice. It rectifies when refreshed.

```
<?php>
$template = "3.2 Ajax comments style";
$nppage = "1";
include 'index.php';
if($_GET['id']){
    require_once('db.php');
    require_once('config.php');

    $cat = array();
    $assignedcats = array();
    $assignedcats = DataAccess::fetch("SELECT news30_cats.name AS catname FROM news30_groupcats
        LEFT JOIN news30_cats ON news30_groupcats.catid = news30_cats.id
        WHERE storyid = ?", $_GET['id']);
    foreach($assignedcats AS $cats){
        $cat[] = $cats['catname'];
}
$static = true;
$nppage = "5";
$template = 'ref_docs';
include 'index.php';
}

?>
```

so I tried incorporate the following [ to force a refresh after the include code is executed. But it doesnt work. Any comments ideas appreciated.

```
$page = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$sec = "10";
header("Refresh: $sec; url=$page");
```

---

I just cant solve this and would appreciate any further help.

I broke my code down to the following. This simply shows news article with blog beneath.

```
<?php
$template = "comments style";
$nppage = "1";
include 'index.php';
?>
```

But after this code is executed I want the page to refresh just once in order to solve loading problems.

I have tried to add

```
<?php
$template = "comments style";
$nppage = "1";
include 'index.php';
{
$page = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$sec = "1";
header("Refresh: $sec; url=$page");
}
?>
```

and

```
<?php
$template = "comments style";
$nppage = "1";
include 'index.php';
{
$page = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$sec = "1";
header("Location: ".$page
}
?>
```

These have not worked. If anyone can offer useful comments i would be obliged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of refresh you may can try to redirect the page to itself. This will appear like a refresh action on the user side.
Try to use 
`header("Location: ".$page)`

Where `$page` is the same that you used.

Comment: fuso. many thanks for that. Still not working. I am trying to install this after the last include so that the page is refreshed after the main code is executed. Do you think this is the right place to include the code ?            [ i  want to refresh just once, as part of the code and continually refreshing the page in general ]

Comment: The php code that you posted is executed only with an Ajax request? Or it is a part of an HTML+PHP page?

Comment: that code is pasted into an HTML page [ at the point at which I want the news and blog ].

Comment: Try to execute it at the top of the page after checking if it need to be reloaded

Comment: The problem, I think, is that you are including again the form part of your page after comment code is executed. I suggest you to use Ajax to get the newer comments and add it dynamically in the page.

Comment: i know what you mean about running the form code twice but I noticed that the problem was solved by 'refresh'. I just reconed that to refresh the page just once [ after code was executed ] would be easiest solution, as a part-time coder  !!   :0)    thanks for ideas though.